# does a directive need to list the service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know there are a few ways to format this but, if a new service is injected into the controller:

```
AnalyticsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'analyticsService', 'nvd3', 'gridster'];
```

Does the service still need to be in the directive in Angular 1.5?

```
import { AnalyticsController } from './analytics.controller';

export class AnalyticsComponent {

  constructor(){
    this.bindings = {
      chartData: '<'
    };
    this.controller = AnalyticsController;
    this.controllerAs = 'vm';
    this.templateUrl = 'analytics/analytics.html';
//Maybe service?
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean in angular 2 ?

Comment: Angular 1.5 (trying to move towards 2 but not using it yet).  @d3l33t answer makes sense, I'm reading https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component to clarify for myself.

Answer (score 1):

After injecting the service use the constructor to expose your class to the service.

```
AnalyticsComponent.$inject = ['$scope', 'analyticsService', 'nvd3', 'gridster'];

export class AnalyticsComponent {
    constructor($scope, analyticsService, nvd3, gridster) {
        this.bindings = {
            chartData: '<'
        };
        this.controller = AnalyticsController;
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
        this.templateUrl = 'analytics/analytics.html';
        this.analyticsService = analyticsService;
    }

    setAnalytics(data) {
        this.analyticsService.methodName(data);
    }
}
```